# DependencyObject Array C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I have a DependencyObject in C# that is used in an array.  Example shown below:

```
private KeywordTag[] tags = new KeywordTag[] {
    new KeywordTag { Tag = "test", IncidenceCount = 2076 },
    new KeywordTag { Tag = "oi", IncidenceCount = 2052 },
    new KeywordTag { Tag = "hmm", IncidenceCount = 1887 },
    new KeywordTag { Tag = "grr", IncidenceCount = 1414 },
    new KeywordTag { Tag = "thanks", IncidenceCount = 1166 }}
```

How would I convert this code to VB.NET?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dummy's response was almost right, VB.Net's syntax has a "WITH" after the constructors.

```
Private tags() As KeywordTag = { _
    New KeywordTag() WITH {.Tag = test", .IncidentCount = 2076}, _
    New KeywordTag() WITH {.Tag = "oi", .IncidentCount = 2052}, _
    New KeywordTag() WITH {.Tag = "hmm", .IncidentCount = 1887}, _
    New KeywordTag() WITH {.Tag = "grr", .IncidentCount = 1414}, _
    New KeywordTag() WITH {.Tag = "thanks", .IncidentCount = 1166} _
    }
```

Comment: I bet there is not blank before "Tag". But this look better the mine, so i deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
Private tags() As KeywordTag = { New KeywordTag { Tag = "test", IncidenceCount = 2076 }, New KeywordTag { Tag = "oi", IncidenceCount = 2052 }, New KeywordTag { Tag = "hmm", IncidenceCount = 1887 }, New KeywordTag { Tag = "grr", IncidenceCount = 1414 }, New KeywordTag { Tag = "thanks", IncidenceCount = 1166 }}
```